# c++: string::insert(string::iterator _where, char _Ch) suddenly not working

Tags: c++, stl

I'm doing some string manipulation, and am looping through a string with a string iterator, and under certain conditions insert a character into the string. Here is the code:

```
string * const Expression::process(char * const s)
{
    if(s == NULL)
    {
        printf("(from Expression::process())\n > NULL data");
        return NULL;
    }

    string *rtrn = new string(s);
    string garbage;

    //EDIT
    rtrn->erase(remove(rtrn->begin(), rtrn->end(), ' '), rtrn->end());

    for(string::iterator j = rtrn->begin(); (j+2) != rtrn->end(); j++)
    {
        if(Operator::isValid(&*j, garbage) != Operator::SYM && *(j+1) == '-' &&            (Operator::isValid(&(*(j+2)), garbage) != Operator::INVALID))
            rtrn->replace(j+1, j+2, "+-");
    }

    rtrn->insert(rtrn->begin(), '(');
    rtrn->append(")");
    for(string::iterator k = rtrn->begin(); k+1 != rtrn->end(); k++)
    {
        if(*k == '-' && !Operator::isValidNum(*(k+1)))
            rtrn->replace(k, k+1, "-1*");
        if((Operator::isValid(&*(k+1), garbage) != Operator::INVALID && (Operator::isValid(&*(k+1), garbage) != Operator::SYM || *(k+1)=='(')) &&
            (Operator::isValid(&*k, garbage) == Operator::VAR || Operator::isValidNum(*k) || *k==')') &&
        !(Operator::isValid(&*k, garbage) == Operator::NUM && Operator::isValid(&*(k+1), garbage) == Operator::NUM))
        {
            if(Operator::isValid(&*k, garbage) == Operator::SYM)
            {
                if(opSymb::valid[garbage]->getArguments())
                    rtrn->insert(k+1, '*');
            }
            else
            {
                rtrn->insert(k+1, '*');
            }
        }
    }

return rtrn;
}
```

When `s` is equal to "20x(5x+3)-6x(5x^2+11/2)", I get a runtime error at `rtrn->insert(k+1, '*');` under the else statement when it gets to "5x^2" in the string. Basically, when it makes the 6<sup>th</sup> insertion, it crashes on me and complains about the iterator + operator being out of range. Although, when I'm debugging, it does pass the correct offset. And it does successfully insert the char into the string, but after the function executes, the iterator is pointing to corrupt data.

Comment: Your erasing loop should be a call to `std::remove` (with the erase-remove idiom, of course).

Comment: Suddenly not working is often in the same class of problems of "it works by coincidence".

Comment: The erase isn't the issue.

Comment: `string *rtrn = new string(s);` *I weep for your code*

Comment: Well I'm trying to learn, so actual explanation of why that's bad practice or how it should be implemented would be helpful. Save the non-constructive criticism

Answer (score 3):

for(string::iterator i = rtrn->begin(); i != rtrn->end(); i++)
    {
        if(*i == ' ')
            rtrn->erase(i);
    }

There are errors in this and all code snippets like this: **for loop can`t be used for deleting element from a container**, becase **erase() - invalidates all iterators related to the container**,
I offer you to **use while loop instead**, here is a short example from another question I answered:

```
string::iterator it = input.begin();

while (it != input.end())
{
     while( it != input.end() && isdigit(*it))
     {
          it = input.erase(it);
     }
     if (it != input.end())
         ++it;
}
```

Comment: So the erasing is corrupting the data? I don't think that's the problem though, because for the string I pass in this scenario, there are no spaces and it never deletes any elements

Comment: No, erasing does not corrupt data, but it *does* invalidate iterators pointing into the string

Comment: Okay, well, that might be a problem in a different instance, but erase was never called on this data.

Comment: With `std::string`, it is not just `erase` that invalidates iterators, but every modifying member function (though in practice, it might be limited to those members that affect the length of the string).

Comment: Okay. This comment actually explains it. How would I safely add/insert memory/characters into the string. Do I need to use resize or something?

Answer (score 0):

So after research and help from you guys, it seems I have to refine my code so that any string functions such as erase, insert, or replace writes over the iterator passed to the function. So I need to change my code to something like this

```
for(string::iterator k = rtrn->begin(), m=k+1; m != rtrn->end(); k=m, m=k+1)
{
    if(*k == '-' && !Operator::isValidNum(*m))
        rtrn->replace(k, m, "-1*");
    if((Operator::isValid(&*m, garbage) != Operator::INVALID && (Operator::isValid(&*m, garbage) != Operator::SYM || *m=='(')) &&
    (Operator::isValid(&*k, garbage) == Operator::VAR || Operator::isValidNum(*k) || *k==')') &&
    !(Operator::isValid(&*k, garbage) == Operator::NUM && Operator::isValid(&*m, garbage) == Operator::NUM))
    {
        if(Operator::isValid(&*k, garbage) == Operator::SYM)
        {
            if(opSymb::valid[garbage]->getArguments())
        rtrn->insert(m, '*');
        }
        else
        {
            m=rtrn->insert(m, '*');
        }
    }
}
```